# Returning value if it's 0

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

i have following class

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public class Order {
    private OrderId orderId;
    private int daysElapsed;
    private List<Item> items;
}
```

Right now, if `daysElapsed` is `0` it is not included as part of response object. I want it to be there. Is there something provided by jackson which can handle this?

I was thinking to use `Integer` class and use annotation `NON_NULL` to exclude it. Is there a better approach to do so?

Comment: Why are you using `Include.NON_DEFAULT`?

Comment: Using `NON_NULL` is still the same issue though, isn't it? If you make daysElapsed an Integer, it's "default" value would be null since it's an object now. I suppose in your constructor, if you used Integer as opposed to int, you could initialize daysElapsed to 0 and it would still be non null, thus working. Seems kind of screwy to me though

Comment: @SaxyPandaBear Unless you leave it as an `int`.

Comment: Well I only asked that because OP asked about using Integers with Include.NON_NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only including `NON_DEFAULT` values. The default value of an `int` field is `0`. So when `daysElapsed` is `0`, its value is equal to the default value, so is not included in the JSON.

Just remove the `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)` annotation.

Comment: I ended up using `NON_NULL` annotation